# Can I add custom cv subcommands in my extension?

Tags: cv

I'm starting to work on our Drupal 7 -> Drupal 9 upgrade path. I have a lot of custom drush commands (that mostly run CiviCRM code) to help with provisioning and I'm wondering what to do with them. One option would be to re-write them as `cv` subcommands - but I don't think that's possible. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Something like `cv php:script --user=admin my_subcommand.php` is kind of the same thing if I understand correctly? You'd just have to put your previous code into a separate php file and adjust.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's workable, but does require typing the path to wherever I put the php file. I suppose I can always stick with drush (or even use drupal console). But, I wonder if there would be interest in developing this feature for `cv`?

Answer (score 1):

I may be over-thinking this. I can simply add apiv4 functions to any extension and then they are all available via: `cv api4 Foo.Bar`. I guess you can extend `cv` after all thanks to the API.